# criteria - select by getter

Tags: java, hibernate, interface, criteria

i have a Interface to get the value for a column whose name can be different.

```
public interface IInterface {

    Integer getValue();
}

class A implements IInterface{
    private Integer someValue;

    public Integer getValue(){
        return someValue;
    }
}

class B implements IInterface{
    private Integer valueAlias;

    public Integer getValue(){
        return valueAlias;
    }
}
```

In an abstract class i want to select the entity with the highest value, but i don't have a explicit column name. 
Is there a possibility to solve this problem?

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<IInterface> cq = cb.createQuery(IInterface.class);
Root<IInterface> root = cq.from(IInterface.class);
cq.select(cb.max(/* getValue() */));
```

Answer (score 0):

Each entity (or table) will need its own implementation, but you can certainly have them both implement the same interface.

Using your `CriteriaBuilder`, you will need need to separately query each entity using the implementation class. Referencing the interface as you've done in your original question will not work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
class A implements IInterface, Serializable {

    @Column(name = "SOME_COL")
    private Integer someValue;

    public Integer getValue(){
        return someValue;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
class B implements IInterface, Serializable {

    @Column(name = "SOME_OTHER_COL")
    private Integer valueAlias;

    public Integer getValue(){
        return valueAlias;
    }
}
```